# why (navigator.devicememory) is not accurate for devices with more than 6gb of ram?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get device Memory (80% of time android phones) I wrote this code.

```
 <html> 
    <body>
    <p class="ram-description">Your device memory is <span id="result">unknown</span> GB.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = navigator.deviceMemory || 'unknown'
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but I think (navigator.deviceMemory) is not working for phones o other devices with more than 4 GB of RAM

for example, my phone has 6GB ram and it shows 4GB
my laptop has 16GB and it shows 8GB

can anyone help me?

```
<html> 
<body>
<p class="ram-description"><b id="result">Your device memory is <b id="result">unknown</b> GiB.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = navigator.deviceMemory || 'unknown'
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

> lower and upper bounds are used to protect privacy of owners of very low- or high-end devices

Quoted from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/deviceMemory

Comment: See also [the spec's section on this](https://w3c.github.io/device-memory/#computing-device-memory-value).

Comment: So can you help me how to get device ram ?

Answer (score 3):

This was puzzling me too, so I dug further into the resources I could find for a good answer to how this API actually works.

The truth is, **it's not possible for a browser script to retrieve a device's precise amount of memory**. That's deliberately not available, as protection against device fingerprinting.

Instead, `Navigator.deviceMemory` gives us something that's usefully accurate but still anonymous: it places the device into a cohort based on the smallest amount of memory it *could* have.

Here's how the calculation should work according to [the definition in the draft spec](https://w3c.github.io/device-memory/#computing-device-memory-value):

1. The browser checks the device's *real* available memory in **mebibytes** (MiB, or "true megabytes" as counted in base-2). Note that this number is processed in *binary*, not decimal. If your Android phone has 6 "marketing-speak GB" of RAM = 6000 MiB, in binary that is `1011101110000`.
2. The browser rounds that binary number *down* to the "most significant bit", which means keeping the leftmost `1` and setting all smaller bits to `0`. This is the same as rounding down to the nearest power of 2. For the phone example, base 2 `1011101110000` becomes `1000000000000` = 2¹² = 4096 MiB.
3. The rounded number is divided by 1024 to get a value in GiB, and this is returned by `Navigator.deviceMemory`. So you get `4` on the Android phone.

The draft also advises limits on the largest and smallest values:

> NOTE: While implementations may choose different values, the recommended upper bound is 8GiB and the recommended lower bound is 0.25GiB (or 256MiB).

This means that every device will be placed in one of 6 possible cohorts: `0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 8`. And that's the best we can do currently. Someone with 0.9995 GB of RAM will report having 0.5 GB, and someone with a 128 GB workstation will report having only 8.

If you're going to use this API to alter your site/app's performance at all (as opposed to just reporting the value to the user like in OP's example), do so prudently. A machine may report having 8 GB of RAM, but if that device is already using 80% of it (and you have no way to know), then you're better off treating it like it only has 1GB. It also only accounts for RAM, and not processor speed, GPU speed/memory, or other performance variables.

Lastly, current browser support is Chromium-only, and someone from the Safari team has said [they won't be adding this API](https://github.com/w3c/device-memory/issues/24) because of its limited usefulness and privacy implications. Caveat emptor.